# jQuery Animation is delayed on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have it set to a div's width increases when I scroll past it with the following code. Now I do this same thing except with .fadeIn() and it works fine. But when I use the .animate() i'll scroll to that location and nothing will happen, but like randomly 30-40 seconds later it will just decide to animate without me even touching/moving anything. Any reason why that is?

HTML

```
<div>

    2500px of CONTENT

</div>

<div class="statbar"></div>
```

CSS

```
.statbar {
   width:100px;
   height:30px;
   background-color:#ff4200;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 2500) {
            $('.statbar').animate({width:'200px'}, 300);
        } else {
            $('.statbar').animate({width:'10px'}, 300);
        }


});
```

Here's a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/kr4yeyw3/2/

If you wait like 30 seconds at the div, you'll see the animation will take place (need it to happen instantly like the fadeIn() does.

EDIT: It works when I change those 300 to zeros, but it doesn't animate! Just changes width instantly without "sliding" it over.

EDIT2: Finally figured it out for anyone who one day scrolls across this page looking for a similar answer.

Adding clearQueue(), stop() and easing seemed to do the trick

```
$('.statbar').clearQueue().stop().animate({width:'75%'}, { "duration": 400, "easing": "linear" });
```

Answer (score 0):

clearQueue or Stop will do fix the animation, but it doesn't address the real problem with your code. In your else statement, which is hit like 2000 times as you scroll to the bottom of the page, you are starting an animation with a duration of 400 milliseconds.

jQuery animate puts all animations into a queue and calls them one after the other so it creates a huge delay before the animation you actually want to see. [api.jquery.com/animate/](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Here's how I think you should rework your code:

```js
var isExpanded = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {

  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > 2500) {
    
    $('.statbar').animate({width:'200px'}, 300);
    isExpanded = true;
    
  } else if(isExpanded) {
    
    $('.statbar').animate({width:'10px'}, 300);
    isExpanded = false;
    
  }
});
```

Here I use a flag to determine if the animation needs to be run and just toggle it as we switch display modes.